# How is a baby girl with a non-Jewish Father given a name?

Tags: torah-service, intermarriage, baby-infant

What is the process for naming a baby girl with a Jewish mother and a non Jewish father?
Typically the father is given an aliyah and the name is given as part of a mishebarach. Does the mother's father get the aliyah? What if he is either not living or also not Jewish? Does an uncle do it or a local community Rav?

Comment: The minhag of doing it by an aliya is not the only way. Covid is a case in point. https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/the-minhag-when-naming-a-baby-daughter-is-for-the-father-to-be-called-to-the-torah-for-an-aliya-after-the-aliya-a-mi-sheberach-is-recited-which-begins-with-a-prayer-for-the-mothers-health-a/

Comment: I've seen grandparents get the Aliya (even not during covid @chatzkel). Not that any of this is a requirement.

Comment: @DoubleAA if there is not an aliyah what other method is used for naming a baby girl?

Comment: @DavefromBaltimore An aliya is not a method of naming. A misheberach is a method of naming (and anyone get say a misheberach for anyone whenever they want). Another method of naming is saying "I shall call her Squishy and she shall be mine and she shall be my Squishy. Come on, Squishy. Come on, little Squishy."

Comment: But what if you want to call her Smushy